# Using Spine.Model.Ajax, how to handle extra properties in the responsed JSON when model updated

Tags: javascript, spine.js

For example:

```
class User extends Spine.Controller
  @configure 'User', 'name'
  @extend Spine.Model.Ajax
  @url: '/save'

user = new User(name: 'test')
user.save()

User.bind 'update', (item) ->
  console.log(item.flag) # undefined
```

say '/save' response `{flag: 0}` because of some database error, when Ajax finished, Spine trigger the update event and update the `user` model, but there is no `flag` property extended to `user` when updated. So, how can I handle this situation when I need to response some extra data that is a little different from model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the document more carefully, I found the answer: see http://spinejs.com/docs/ajax [Custom serialization]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.